# The label 'N' has already been declared. Label names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net

I have a question.

I need to make a program in vb.net that needs to set text in a sql database.
But everytime when I click on Export to Database the program shuts down and says:

> The label 'N' has already been declared. Label names must be unique
>   within a query batch or stored procedure

I don't know what this means, I'm new to .net languages. Hope someone can help me.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\klaasjelle\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Opdracht\Opdracht\Opdracht1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"

    con.Open()

    cmd.Connection = con

    cmd.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO opdracht ('FilePath', 'ImageSide', 'ImageSize') VALUES ('{TextBox1.Text}')"

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Sub
```

Comment: So when you create a new row, you have three columns (FilePath, ImageSize, ImageSize) but you give it only one value... Without mentionning the possible SQL injection there

Comment: Use parametrized queries and do dispose the command and connection.

Comment: @Lucero Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Klaas-JelleRas I gave a comment with the necessary keywords to [find the answer all around you](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvb.net%5D+parametrized+sql+query) and in [FAQs](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6bdf8b71-1cf1-41c0-848c-4fca2c9e1ea2/faq-how-do-i-make-a-parameterized-query-in-the-database-with-vbnet). There's no point in providing yet another example of the same thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not valid Command text there i suppose.

```
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO opdracht (FilePath, ImageSide, ImageSize) VALUES ('"
 + TextBox1.Text + "')"
```

Comment: His should be valid, because he is using the $ symbol which allows you to inline variable names and property names with {}